# Truffle test including mainnet contract - Error: Cannot create instance of Whitelist; no code at address

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test, mainnet

Problem with the error `Error: Cannot create instance of Whitelist; no code at address 0x6198149b79AFE8114dc07b46A01d94a6af304ED9`

How do I have to setup truffle so that I can run a test which includes data from a mainnet contract while the test itself runs on the development chain?

**TESTWhitelistAdvanced.js**

```
contract("WhitelistAdvanced Tests", async accounts => {
  var whitelist;

  before(async () => {
    whitelist = await Whitelist.at("0x6198149b79AFE8114dc07b46A01d94a6af304ED9");
  });
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    mainnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/" + infuraKey, 0),
      network_id: 1,       // Mainnet's id
      gas: 9975000,        // Block gas
     }
}
```

**2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
const Whitelist = artifacts.require("Whitelist");
const WhitelistAdvanced = artifacts.require("WhitelistAdvanced");

module.exports = function (deployer, network) {
  if (network === 'mainnet') {
    // DO NOT DEPLOY ANYTHING HERE!
  } else {
    deployer.deploy(Whitelist);
    deployer.deploy(WhitelistAdvanced);
  }
};
```

Comment: What is your `network` configuration (in file `truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js`)?

Comment: BTW, the `contract` function in Truffle tests takes a regular function, not an `async` function.

Comment: We also need to see migration script to see how WhiteList is deployed. Because, I am assuming from the error message, there is contract deployed at this address and this is what truffle is saying.

Comment: I mean. There is no contract deployed at this address.

Comment: @RobMagier updated the question with these files. To clarify, the contract I try to get information from is on the Mainnet. You can check the address, it exists. Put I wanna test on the local chain.